# Gomobile no exported names in the package

Tags: go, gomobile

I am trying to bind the following code with gomobile to export it as a framework for iOS. I have done this before successfully but for some reason the following code, when I run the bind command gives me the error gomobile: no exported names in the package . The code works when ran as a go script.

```
   package request

import (
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
)

func requestEndpoint(number string) string {

    safeNumber := url.QueryEscape(number)
  url := fmt.Sprintf("http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key=690a581e85900555754fd7bfa70808b2&number=%s&country_code=&format=1", safeNumber)


   return url

  }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function `requestEndpoint` should be changed to `RequestEndpoint`. The capitalized function is considered as exported within the package.

Answer (score -1):

You should try

$ gomobile bind -target=ios

$ grep request ./Request.framework/*